# 'for' loop and typecasting hell ! (PHP)

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

//matches[0] holds some preg_match'ed values

```
for($i=0;$i<count($matches[0]);$i++)
 {

  $price = $matches[0][$i]; //a**uto type casting to (float) returns 0 for $price. Tried it for values greater than 1 too.**
  //echo gettype($price);
  $price = $price + 0.01; **//Returns 0 + 0.01 instead of the right answer**
    //**even after removing the above statement it does not compare**
    if($price <= 1.50 && $price >= 1.00){ //because it should auto type cast to float, which it does no...
      echo "here";
        $price = $price+0.50;}
    //strcmp always returns a '1' where 1 is surely not expected (not equal)
    else if(strcmp($price,"1.50") > 0)  && strcmp($price,"2.00") < 0 ){
      echo "here 2";
        $price = $price+0.50;}   

 }
```

Does this not work because $price is a constant as it belongs to a loop ?

I tried the same thing normally, without the loop, and it typecasts properly.

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: What's the code that generates `$matches`?  The regular expression in particular would be helpful. My best guess at the moment is that it's got some whitespace, so $price = `trim($matches[0][$i]);` would help but I doubt that's the whole solution.

Comment: The regex is :-
<br />

preg_match_all("/<price>(\d|\.)+<\/price>/",$data,$matches);

Also, the trim did not work. good thought though.

Comment: $data is got from a file

Comment: Because foreach gave the same problem ... so I thought maybe the for loop would solve it .....

Comment: Further, later in the code, in the for loop, I also use 

$matches[0][$i] = str_replace(".","\.",$matches[0][$i]); //for escaping the '.'
 
 
  $data = preg_replace("/<price>".$matches[0][$i]."<\/price>/",$price,$data,1);

but it gives me this error

"Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'g' in"

$matches[0][$i] has 1.80 as it's vlaue

Comment: What are the echoed values of `$matches[0][$i]`?

Comment: $matches[0][0] is 5.51
$matches[0][1] is 1.80

those are echoed

Comment: How did you declare `$price`?

Comment: It doesn't matter **how** you loop over the variables, the types won't change that easily. Could you simply post the result of `var_dump($matches)`? Into your question please, it's unreadable in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something I found which doesn't necessarily solve the entire thing:

Never compare floats for inequality.

```
var_dump(0.7 + 0.1 == 0.8);
```

outputs `false`. No kidding.

> This is due to the fact that it is
> impossible to express some fractions
> in decimal   notation with a finite
> number of digits. For instance, 1/3 in
> decimal form becomes 0.3.
>
> If higher precision is necessary, the
> [arbitrary precision math functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) and
> [gmp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php) functions are available.

Source: [PHP: Floating point numbers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) check out the warning part

Also, you could use PHP's **[SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/simplexml)** instead of preg_matching the tags manually.

Comment: Thanks for the resource, but none of the functions there worked.

Comment: What is ahppening is that $price is first a string, But as soon as it is converted to a float, it is re-intialized to '0'.

Comment: "If the string starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used. Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero)."

hm...looking further into it.....

http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

Comment: Have you considered using SimpleXML? (added to my answer)

Comment: How was the `$price` variable declared?

Comment: declared it as both $price = "0.00"; and as $price = 0.00

None seem to work.

Comment: Try declaring as `$price = 0.00` and explicitly cast `$matches[0][$i]` like this: `(float) $matches[0][$i]` then you'll have `$price = (float) $matches[0][$i]`.

Comment: Nope. Still reinitializes to 0 in case of explicit typecast...
Thanks for the help Randell.

Comment: I suggest that you debug this thing by divide and conquer. Remove working codes until you are able to isolate the non-working code. Then start from there.

Comment: It has something to do with the preg_match.
 This is because when I overwrite $matches values like so,

$matches[0][0] = "5.51";
$matches[0][1] = "1.80";

then the code works....

Comment: Someone please slap me. I made an old mistake of not looking at the page source. What was outputted to the browser was $matches[0][0] = '<price>5.51</price>' but the browser showed only 5.51.
 This was due to the regular expression. slap slap slap.....

Comment: Hey, you might want to post your answer as the correct answer so as to finish this thread.

Answer (score 1):

`$matches[0][$i]` contains the whole expression, including the tags. To refer to the ***1***st capture (the thing in parenthesis) use this instead:

```
$price = $matches[1][$i];
```

Or better yet, replace your `for` loop with `foreach`:

```
foreach ($matches[1] as $price)
```

Also, take a look at [assignment operators](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php), see how you can greatly simplify some expressions such as

```
$price += 0.50;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [SimpleXML](http://php.net/simplexml) to get the values from your xml string/file/source (as mentioned before) and the [BC Math functions](http://php.net/ref.bc) which allows you to ship around most precision limitiations.

```
<?php
$items = new SimpleXMLElement(getXml());
// setting bcmath's default scale to two (digits after the .)
bcscale(2); 

foreach( $items as $item ) {
  $price = bcadd($item->price, '0.01');
  echo $price, " -> ";
  if ( -1<bccomp($price, '1.00') && 1>bccomp($price, '1.50') ) {
    $price = bcadd($price, '0.50');
    echo 'a) price+0.50=', $price, "\n";
  }
  else if ( 0<bccomp($price, '1.50') && 1>bccomp($price, '2.00') ) {
    $price = bcadd($price, '0.50');
    echo 'b) price+0.50=', $price, "\n";
  }
  else {
    $price = bcadd($price, '0.10');
    echo 'c) price+0.10=', $price, "\n";
  }
}

function getXml() {
  return '<foo>
    <item>
      <description>a</description>
      <price>1.48</price>
    </item>
    <item>
      <description>b</description>
      <price>1.49</price>
    </item>
    <item>
      <description>c</description>
      <price>1.50</price>
    </item>
    <item>
      <description>d</description>
      <price>1.99</price>
    </item>
    <item>
      <description>e</description>
      <price>2.00</price>
    </item>
  </foo>';
}
```

prints

```
1.49 -> a) price+0.50=1.99
1.50 -> a) price+0.50=2.00
1.51 -> b) price+0.50=2.01
2.00 -> b) price+0.50=2.50
2.01 -> c) price+0.10=2.11
```